# How can I run the command startActivity(Intent i) without a button press or anything?

Tags: android, actionlistener

So in Android Studio, I'm working on an app that uses a web scraper library to scan a web page, and when it recognizes a certain string on the page, it places a phone call automatically. However, because this code simply runs in my main method, I get a compile error when I try to call the startActivity function.

I'm new to android development, but from what I've gathered so far, it seems that the startActivity function can only be called from a method like inside of a Listener of some kind. So, what is the best workaround for this? Thanks!

Here is the method that I'm talking about:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ResponseException, NotFound {
        user = new UserAgent();
        while (true) {
            if (canCheck()) {
                user.visit("https://twitter.com/******");
                Element mostRecentTweet = user.doc.findFirst("<div class=\"tweet-text\"");
                System.out.println(mostRecentTweet.innerText());
                if (lastTweet != null) {
                    if (mostRecentTweet.innerText().equals(lastTweet.innerText())) {
                        String phoneNumber = searchForNumber(mostRecentTweet.innerText());
                        if (phoneNumber != null) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
                lastTweet = mostRecentTweet;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "because this code simply runs in my main method" -- what "main method"? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I removed all the default methods like onCreate() and onNavigationDrawerItemSelected() and replaced it with a public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: How were you planning on running this app? What do you expect will be calling this `main()` method?

Comment: Well I normally program with vanilla java in NetBeans, and I know that public static void main is called automatically when it runs. Like I said, I'm new to android so I'm really not sure

Comment: Android apps do not contain a `main()` method that is automagically called. Even in classic Java, `main()` is only used in some circumstances (e.g., you are creating a complete program, rather than a plugin for something else, such as a Web app). How do you plan on a user using your Android app? Will they tap some home screen launcher icon?

Comment: No, I want the app to run by itself and when it finally does find the String on the webpage, activate a call automatically. The user does not have to press anything

Comment: "I want the app to run by itself" -- well, *something* has to trigger it to run. If the user not going to click a launcher icon as the trigger, what do you plan on using as a trigger?

Comment: @CommonsWare, if by clicking the launcher icon you mean just opening the app, then yes, the user will do that, but then the app will continuously scan in the background is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is rather complicated, as it involves a number of things that users dislike: continuously-running background work, placing phone calls without user intervention, etc.

To do work on a periodic basis, the simplest solution is to [use `JobScheduler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html), where your application logic will go in a `JobService` subclass. You would then need an activity that, perhaps in response to clicking a button, will schedule the periodic work with the `JobScheduler`. Note that your jobs will run irregularly, and on Android 6.0+ devices they will run infrequently when your app moves into app standby mode and when the device is in Doze mode.

In your `JobService`, you can fetch the data from the Internet. However, you cannot easily start an activity, because doing so is actively user-hostile. You have no idea what the user is doing in the foreground at the time, and taking over the screen to place a phone call will interrupt the user. A far better solution is to raise a `Notification`, perhaps a priority "heads-up" one, that allows the user to place the phone call if the user wants.

`ACTION_CALL` requires the `CALL_PHONE` permission, and if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, you will need to implement [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) in your activity, as the user has to agree to allow you to place phone calls on the user's behalf.

Answer (score -1):

Use a background service that generates an event when webscraper library finds a string and then regsiter a broadcast receiver in your app that listens to this event.For background services read this artcicle https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/choosing-the-right-background-scheduler-in-android/ hope it helps